# How can I sort this arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array by a array key. I looked at array_multisort,
array_multisort($result['EVENT'], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
but it sorting only event array values

I need to sort by the EVENT values (DESC Order),

My array looks like this:
Array
(
[POLICY] => Array
(
[0] => 278395
[1] => 278395
)
[EVENT] => Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
)

```
    [EVENT_TYPE] => Array
        (
            [0] => INITIAL POLICY
            [1] => POLICY CORRECTION
        )

    [DATE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03-JAN-20
            [1] => 18-JUN-20
        )
)
```

Expected output:
Array
(
[POLICY] => Array
(
[0] => 278395
[1] => 278395
)
[EVENT] => Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => 1
)

```
    [EVENT_TYPE] => Array
        (
            [0] => POLICY CORRECTION
            [1] => INITIAL POLICY
        )

    [DATE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-JUN-20
            [1] => 03-JAN-20
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the other sub arrays as arguments to `array_multisort`, so they get reordered together with the EVENT column:

```
array_multisort($result["EVENT"], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, 
                $result["POLICY"],
                $result["EVENT_TYPE"],
                $result["DATE"]);
```